# FB graph api Profile feed (Wall) is not the same as Wall?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I'm using : graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=... to get my wall in json format, however, I can't get all the wall. I can get almost all.

I can get the posts where I'am tagged with @my_name..
I can't get the posts where I'am invoqued by "Who are you with?" option..

however, in the wall web application y can see both messages. but using graph api not.

The documentaion says: "Profile feed (Wall): graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=." ..

I thinks the Wall == graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token... but apparently I'm wrong :( ..

Thanks in advance ..

Edit.. more information:

Image 1: We can see posts 1,2,3 and 4 (in red) in the wall ..

Image 2: We can see that the posts 2 and 4 had disappeared of json result.

both, post 2 and 4 are using "Who are you with?" "With hall9000"..

Image 1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1mFp.png
Image 2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kIKG.png

Comment: Can you provide more details about the post you can't see? Maybe even post a screenshot?

Comment: I added more information.. any suggestions??

Comment: I just noticed the "android" tag on this question. Were the missing posts (2 and 4) posted with an Android phone? Was the official Facebook application used, or an Android application of your own making?

Comment: No android.. the client doesn't matter.. the problem is with the api.. thank.. see screenshot.